# C++ function calculating the area of a triangle

Tags: c++

I have the following function in C++ that is supposed to find the area of a triangle using Heron's formula. I haven't made any mistake in the math but it doesn't produce the right result! I am looking at it for more than 3 hours and I can't find any mistake. What am I missing?

```
float TriangleArea(float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    float area_triangle;
    float a, b, c, s;

    a=std::sqrt((x0-x1)*(x0-x1)-(y0-y1)*(y0-y1));
    b=std::sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)-(y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
    c=std::sqrt((x0-x2)*(x0-x2)-(y0-y2)*(y0-y2));

    s=(a+b+c)/2;

    area_triangle=std::sqrt((s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)));

    return area_triangle;

}
```

Comment: Please provide sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Are any of the subexpressions already wrong?

Comment: `I am looking at it for more than 3 hours`  Then print out each of those values of `a`, `b`, and `c`, and the computation of the semiperimeter `s` and see which is not correct.   Writing 3 or 4 `printf()` or `cout` lines doesn't take 3 hours.

Comment: Phytagoras, maybe...  :-)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I used `cout` lines but I only figured that I had a mistake not where it was. :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I haven't made any mistake in the math but it doesn't produce the right result!

If it's not producing the right result, then I think there's a very high chance you made a mistake in the math.

> ```
> a=std::sqrt((x0-x1)*(x0-x1)-(y0-y1)*(y0-y1));
> ```

That `-` looks suspicious. I'm assuming you're trying to find the distance between `(x0, y0)` and `(x1, y1)`. If that's the case, you should be adding the two quantities, not subtracting.

I'm not familiar with Heron's formula, but [you can use this simpler formula](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordtrianglearea.html):

```
area = std::abs(x0 * (y1 - y2) + x1 * (y2 - y0) + x2 * (y0 - y1)) / 2;
```

**Edit:** I forgot to mention the `abs` function for the simplified formula, which was pointed out by [Antonio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376366/c-function-calculating-the-area-of-a-triangle/29376698#29376698).

Comment: Looking at Heron's formula, he is indeed computing the lengths of the sides, which means it should be `+` and not `-`

Comment: You are so right! I hadn't even realized that I used "-" as it was so elementary and I was looking for mistakes in the formula. Thank you!

Comment: As a side note, your formula can also be used to check if the 3 points are collinear (the area turns out to be zero)

Comment: @Antonio: Isn't that true of pretty much any triangle-area formula?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a sign error. The values a, b, and c are the triangle sides, right?

```
a=std::sqrt((x0-x1)*(x0-x1)+(y0-y1)*(y0-y1));
                           ^
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right! I had to accept the other answer though as it was the first one and provides additional information.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative formula (with demonstration) can be found [here](http://www.mathguru.com/level2/application-of-coordinate-geometry-2007101600011139.aspx)

```
area = fabs((x0 - x2) * (y1 - y0) - (x0 - x1) * (y2 - y0) ) / 2;
```

(As a side note, if the formula has to be used to test points collinearity, the absolute value can be removed... But then you might need it anyway, as working with floating points you cannot test equality but against some epsilon value)